# Cannot access self hosted signal r in Azure VM externally

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-virtual-machine

I have self hosted signal r console application which I need to run within a VM on Azure

I need to be able to access the hub externally

I cannot host this via Azure App Services because it is using Selenium

I have opened up Port 8080 via the Azure Portal but when I try to access the address (via public ip) I get nothing

Is there anything else I need to do?

Paul

Comment: First, ensure your service is running and  check if you opened the port 8080 both NSG and firewall in your machine. If you have any error details you can post in your question.:-)

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT nsg?

Comment: Yep,Network security group. You also need to open the port here. Please refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal

Comment: Hi,@Paul   May I know that did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yep it did thanks! I also needed to use http://*:8080 in my host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with Wayne advice and needed to use http://localhost:8080 in my host